# Identify removable devices from mount point in kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, mount-point

I'm writing a kernel module and I want to know if a given mount point is associated with a removable device. Is there any way to do that?

For example, when I list all the mounts using `cat /proc/mounts` I get something like this:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/mosa/DELLRESTORE vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1001,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
...
```

So I have 3 mount points `/`, `/boot/efi`, and `/media/mosa/DELLRESTORE`.. the 3rd one is a removable device.

I want a way in a kernel module, given a mount point (e.g. `/media/mosa/DELLRESTORE`) tell me if it's associated with a removable device or not.

Comment: `lsblk` will tell you if the drive is removable. It's the `RM` column.

Comment: @Andy I'm aware of `lsblk` but I've read that it's not a good idea to call userspace applications from a kernel module. Is there a way to do that from the kernel module, using kernel APIs maybe?